# How can I add an auto response e-mail and a confirmation message to my contact form

Tags: php

I would really appreciate if someone could help me with my 2 questions. I have a contact form and I want to:
1) show a confirmation message to the user, once he clicks submit.
2) send a confirmation e-mail to the user, once he clicks submit.

My contact_process.php is:

```
    <?php

include dirname(dirname(__FILE__)).'/mail.php';

error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

$post = (!empty($_POST)) ? true : false;

if($post)
{
include 'email_validation.php';

$name = stripslashes($_POST['name']);
$email = trim($_POST['email']);

$error = '';

// Check name

if(!$name)
{
$error .= 'Please enter your name.<br />';
}

// Check email

if(!$email)
{
$error .= 'Please enter an e-mail address.<br />';
}

if($email && !ValidateEmail($email))
{
$error .= 'Please enter a valid e-mail address.<br />';
}

if(!$error)
{
$mail = mail(CONTACT_FORM, $subject,
     "From: ".$name." <".$email.">\r\n");

if($mail)
{
echo 'OK';
}

}
else
{
echo '<div class="notification_error">'.$error.'</div>';
}

}
?>
```

And my email_validation.php is:

```
<?php
function ValidateEmail($value)
{
    $regex = '/^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i';

    if($value == '') { 
        return false;
    } else {
        $string = preg_replace($regex, '', $value);
    }

    return empty($string) ? true : false;
}
?>
```

If anyone could help with adding the missing code, that would be amazing. I am a beginner at this.

Thank you!

Sorin

Comment: What missing code ? You didn't describe any problem nor asked any question

Comment: For sending emails i recommend SwiftMailer library (https://swiftmailer.symfony.com/docs/introduction.html).
See its documentation for details on preparing and sending emails.